# External hard drive (WD20EZAZ) shows up as SSD in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, ssd, external-hard-drive

I have a WD20EZAZ drive in a generic, usb (ssk branded) hdd dock.  Windows defrag (also defraggler)  thinks it's an SSD.

Things I have tried:

- reformatting the drive in both windows and linux (both as ntfs)
- `winsat formal` and `winsat diskformal` with and without restarting afterwards
- switching which slot the drive is in (the dock is dual bay)
- using the `Set-PhysicalDisk` command to force the device to display HDD instead of SSD
- uninstalling and reinstalling the drive and the dock in device manager

Comment: Does it literally say "SSD" or does it just show it differently from other HDDs? It's an SMR HDD so maybe Windows is confused by it supporting TRIM...

Comment: In every command line tool it says 'SSD'.  In the defrag tool, it says solid state drive https://i.imgur.com/xQp6DBE.png